# Titanium Alloy - Animating window on Android

Tags: javascript, android, animation, titanium

I'm fairly new to Titanium Alloy, last 2 weeks i've been digging in the docs & Q/A to figure out how to animate open a window but none of the solutions work for me or just partly.

This is where i got so far - the slide_in_up is working, but the closing animation **slide_out_down** is not. Strange is, when i change the close animation to slide_out_right, it works.

I've got the animation xml files in /platform/android/res/anim/slide_in_up.xml and slide_out_down.xml

Am i doing something wrong?

My index.js

```
$.cardbut.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var cardwin = Alloy.createController('card').getView();

    cardwin.open({
        activityEnterAnimation : Ti.App.Android.R.anim.slide_in_up,

    });
    cardwin.addEventListener('android:back', function() {

        cardwin.close({
            activityExitAnimation : Ti.Android.R.anim.slide_out_down
        });
    });

});
```

My card.js

```
function backHome(){
      $.card.close({
            activityExitAnimation : Ti.Android.R.anim.slide_right,

        });
}
```

and card.xml

```
    <Alloy>
    <Window  exitOnClose="false" modal="true" navBarHidden="true"  fullscreen="true" layout="vertical">
        <View id="topbar">
            <ImageView id="topbarimage" ></ImageView>
        </View>
        <View onClick="backHome" width="100%" height="150" backgroundColor="#880000">
        <Label>Card page</Label>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define activityExitAnimation while calling open({...}).

Support for this attribute in close() will be added in the future version https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-13543?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel